# c++ pointer to pointer of an int

Tags: c++, pointers

If I have:

```
int **p;
```

why can't I do this?

```
p = new *int[4];
```

but if I have:

```
class T {...}
T **c;
c = new *T[4];
```

is that correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `*` has to come after the type-name that it modifies:

```
p = new int*[4];
c = new T*[4];
```

Comment: Still, why is that not the case with the template?

Comment: @JonoRR: I don't see any templates. The second case, with a class type, is just as wrong as the first.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not correct.

the `*` must go after the *type-name*.

Then it should be:

```
p = new int*[4];
```

And

```
c = new T*[4];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to multiply the keyword `new` with the type (`int` or `T`)!  To say you want a `new` array of pointers to `int`:

```
p = new int*[4];
```

or an array of pointers to `T`:

c = new T*[4];